# How to create a view area handler

Tags: views, commerce

I'm building a Drupal Commerce store. On cart view I need to display some additional information.

I want to create area handler like Commerce Order: Total. It should do some php logic and display the results.

Can anybody give me some advice how to build such a handler? The documentation didn't gave me much information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom module and override default area handler using hook_views_data_alter().

The default implementation of order total handler placed [here](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!order!includes!views!handlers!commerce_order_handler_area_order_total.inc/DC).

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. implement hook_views_data_alter() to declare the area handler, and specify the name of the class that implements the handler.
2. Implement the handler class, extending views_area_handler, and override the methods you need.

I wrote such an area handler for views_autorefresh some months back, find the code here: http://drupalcode.org/project/views_autorefresh.git/commitdiff/2bafcd7?hp=9108ef808df5165e946eb09cebe5bc6c9112acd2