# Custom redirect for form-edit displayed in Views header

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type called '*Checklist*' which I bring forward using Views, in it's node-edit form.

I wrote PHP code within the header in order to do this, here it is:

```
<?php 

    $view = views_get_current_view();
    $arg0 = $view->args[0];

    $nodeToLoad = $view->result[0]->nid; //I get the node to load from Fields within my view
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');

    $node = node_load($nodeToLoad);
    dsm($nodeToLoad);
    $edit_page = drupal_get_form('page_node_form', $node);

    $edit_page['additional_settings']['#access'] = FALSE;
    $edit_page['buttons']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'redirect_submit';
    print drupal_render($edit_page );

    function redirect_submit($form, &$form_state){
        $form_state['redirect'] = 'www.google.com';
    }
?>
```

Now what I want is to add a *custom redirect upon saving* this particular form.

I've tried this to no avail:

```
    $edit_page['buttons']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'redirect_submit';
    print drupal_render($edit_page );

    function redirect_submit($form, &$form_state){
        $form_state['redirect'] = 'www.google.com';
    }
```

Is it possible to this within the Views header?

---

**Notes:**

- I have also done this with the *Rules* module but I'd like to learn
  if it's possible to do with PHP code in the Views header so I don't
  split functionality in 2 parts of my project.
- This can also be easily done using a custom hook but again, if it's
  possible to do this within the Views header then that's the trick I'm looking
  for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to use [hook_form_FORM_ID](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7). Something like this:

```
function mymodule_form_page_node_form_ater(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
   if(current_path() == 'page/where/my/view/is'){
     $form_state['redirect'] = 'page/to/redirect';
   }
}
```

If you don't want to use a hook, you can do something like this:

```
 $edit_page['buttons']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'redirect_submit';
```

Then,

```
 function redirect_submit($form, &$form_state){
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'path/to/rediect';
 }
```

Still it is bad practice to inlcude php in your views header. You should implement a custom area handler.

1. [How to create a view area handler](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78575/how-to-create-a-view-area-handler)
2. https://api.drupal.org/api/views/handlers!views_handler_area.inc/group/views_area_handlers/7
3. https://oliverhuynh.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/custom-views-handler-drupal-7-template/

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I've clearly stated in the 'Notes' section of my question that I would like NOT to use custom hooks. Code that can fit in the Views header PHP code(*like the rest of my code*) is what I'm looking for.

Comment: It is very bad practice to write php code in your views header/footer/fields. I strongly recommend to review your approach to this problem. I will adjust my answer

Comment: Thanks, did not know that. Why do you consider it bad practice? I like the idea of having all the code located within that particular View, *if* the code is simple enough.

Comment: hm, I'm updating the question with the suggested code you gave me. It's still not redirecting for some reason..

Comment: Try redirecting to an internal page of your website

Comment: If that doesn't do the trick try adding $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE

Comment: nevermind, i've used Rules module to redirect after the save